# Why is knowing (or approximating) the hamiltonian of atoms important?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, physical-chemistry, perturbation-theory

I know this is a qualitative question but I think it's an important one. I'm currently going through quantum physics and quantum chemistry, and a huge part of this (especially in chem) is approximating the Hamiltonians of atoms with methods such as perturbation theory. What important things does this allow you to do that you could not otherwise accomplish? Why is knowing the energy (or other eigenvalues) important in the real physical world? Ideally, what are some applications that require such knowledge?

Comment: Besides the whole chemistry thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hamiltonian determines the time evolution of a system. In other words, given the way our system is *now*, the hamiltonian tells us how we expect it to behave later. Diagonalizing the hamiltonian to find the energy eigenstates and eigenvalues gives us a convenient way to represent the different possible behaviors of the system and predict how the system will behave in the future.

For example, one thing we can find is the eigenstate with the lowest energy eigenvalue — the ground state. This is typically the most stable configuration of a system and the one we are likeliest to find it in most of the time. Knowing the ground state lets us predict things like how we can expect electric charge to be distributed in different parts of an atom or molecule.

Knowing the energies of the eigenstates with higher energies — the excited states — tells us what changes in energy our system can undergo. Since energy is conserved, those changes are accompanied by emissions or absorptions of energy. For example, an atom can transition from a higher energy state to a lower energy state, emitting light in the process. If we know the energy difference between the states in question, we can predict the wavelengths of light that can be emitted by the atom.

In general, we can write *any* state of the system as a sum of energy eigenstates. Since the rule for how the energy eigenstates change in time very simple, this gives us a relatively simple way to predict how an arbitrary state will change in time.

For complex systems with lots of particles, like a fluid or a crystalline solid, there may be excited states representing, for example, sound waves traveling in the system. Knowing these excited states and their energies lets us predict things like how the system will vibrate if we try to squeeze it or tap on it.

I could go on with infinite examples, but hopefully this gives you an idea of some of the practical things we can do with the hamiltonian and its spectrum. Writing down the hamiltonian is the main way we make predictions about anything in quantum physics.

Answer (score 1):

For applications in Chemistry, you could ask in chemistry stack exchange.

As for physics, if you know the energy eigenstates that means you can solve for how the system evolves in time for any initial state through just an integral, which is generally the goal of physics - to use some laws to predict (in some sense) the future. To rephrase, solving for energy eigenstates/eigenvalues is usually the first step to solving the more general time-dependent Schrödinger equation.

Besides this I can point out that one of the most straightforward quantities that we can measure in experiment is the energy.

Answer (score 1):

In both atomic and molecular physics, interactions between atoms or molecules and other particles (other atoms, molecules, photons, quasiparticles, etc.) is determined by the geometry of the electrons and possibly nuclei within the atoms or molecules.

The geometry of these objects is of course described by the quantum wave functions which are determined from the Hamiltonians. If you better understand the hamiltonians you can better understand the geometry and interactions.

the eigenenergies are important because (1) you calculate them as a step toward calculating the wave functions and (2) they act as labels for different states which have different types of geometries. And of course the energy levels of the different states ALONG WITH the geometry of those states determine some of the features of the interactions.